# I am new to flutter I am trying to run my app and I am getting this 'kotlin-android' plugin requires one of the Android Gradle plugins

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I am new to flutter I am trying to run my app and I am getting this 'kotlin-android' plugin requires one of the Android Gradle plugins.

THIS IS THE ERROR that displayed when i tried to run the app.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> 'kotlin-android' plugin requires one of the Android Gradle plugins.
> Please apply one of the following plugins to ':' project:

- com.android.application
- com.android.library
- com.android.dynamic-feature
- com.android.asset-pack
- com.android.asset-pack-bundle
- com.android.lint
- com.android.test
- com.android.instantapp
- com.android.feature

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

this my android/app/build gradle file

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the 
local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
     }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
   }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID 
(https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.woerrortisunmi"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
     }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    //classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle-settings:7.4.2."
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.0.2')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

HERE IS MY ANDROID/BUILD-GRADLE FILE

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
       // gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        //mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2'
        }
        jcenter()

        //url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0'
        //classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-settings:7.4.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        //classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
     }
 }

 allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        //mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2'
        }
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
apply plugin: "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android"
```

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Answer (score 0):

your build.gradle should be like this

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://storage.googleapis.com/r8-releases/raw'
    }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools:r8:1.5.25'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
  }
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```